# How to force MacOS to scan for duplicate photos?

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I have recently imported a lot of pictures into the Mac Photos App and cannot get it to scan for duplicates. The import caused many pictures to be duplicates and it actually found two duplicates. For the rest it said it will continue once the Mac is plugged in and the photos app is not in use.

Now I tried leaving my Mac plugged in with the App open, with it open in the background, with it closed... All for like 12+h while not using the Mac and having the screensaver set to never time out.

It will not scan any more photos. Is there anything I am doing wrong or anything I can do to force this scan?

Comment: What version of Photos? What version of macOS?

Comment: It's not quite clear here. Are you looking for a way to find duplicates or only to make Photos app scan for those?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica The latest versions for both: MacOS 13.4 and also the Photos app is up to date.

Comment: @Thinkr Well I am looking for duplicates, ideally by having the Photos app scan for them. The app, however, does not do that.